# How to safely restart hudson/jenkins deployed on tomcat without InterruptedException thrown?

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson

I have an hudson instance deployed on tomcat, example: http://xyz:8080/hudson

i have a senario, When i restart hudson instance from within apache , everytime an InterruptedException is thrown on all the job running.

Based on InterruptedException thrown on jobs i am doing some clean up job, which should be ideally called when red cross button on the job is clicked, Not when hudson instance is restarted.

Is there a way to restart hudson instance deployed on tomacat where InterruptedException is not thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepare Jenkins instance to shutdown, it will wait for all jobs to end and every new job will be hold in queue. You need to go to `Manage Jenkins` -> `Prepare for Shutdown`. This way you can safely restart Jenkins process, without loosing any data. Jobs queued to build will start building after restart.

Comment: Thanks!! I was looking for something like this.

Comment: Is there a way Jenkins can send a alert when all the running jobs are completed and system is ready to restart? This is because say for example you already have a job running which may run for hours.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such feature, you need to check it by hand or use REST API.